# How to get image article from rss feed windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, rss-reader

I want to add article's image to listview from rss feed in windows 10

I try this article to add rss feed : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-perform-RSS-Reader-4803093b

But I can't add article's image in listview

Answer (score 0):

For adding image to you listview items you need to define the Listview DataTemplate to something like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Source={Binding img} Height="100"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"/> 
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then you can provide the image source and text to each item by creating a list of items from your RSS Feed and then assigning your `ListView` item source to this list.

Comment: The problem is source of image

Comment: does your rss feed have image source in it ? if not you have to get a rss feed with images in it .. or you can add your own images when you are making the list of items.